# Assume that $p$ is a prime such that there is an integer $a$ with $a^2\equiv -2\pmod{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Assume that $p$ is a prime such that there is an integer $a$ with $a^2\equiv -2\pmod{p}$.
>
> 1. Prove there are integers $x,y$ with $0<x,y<\sqrt{p}$ with $x^2+2y^2\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.
> 2. Conclude that if $n=x^2+2y^2$, then $n=p$ or $n=2p$.
> 3. Prove that $p$ can be written of the form $x^2+2y^2$.

I'm pretty lost here. We have proven very basic things about sums of squares, none of which seems to be relevant to even begin with this problem.

Comment: I imagine your lecturer has proved Fermat's theorem that if $p\equiv1\pmod4$ then $p=x^2+y^2$ for some $x$ and $y$. This exercise is just asking for a variant of that proof.

Comment: What jumps out at me is that the first equation is equivalent to $(x/y)^2 = - 2 \pmod{p}$. Could you try using that?

Comment: Have you had the theory that if $p $ is prime you can always solve $x^2=a\mod p $ and $by=c\mod p $ for $b\ne 0$.  Solve $x^2=1\mod p $ and $z^2=p-1\mod p$ and $2y=z \mod p $.

Comment: Oh.  I didn't notice that you had $a^2=-2$!  Just take y=1 and x=a!

Comment: @fleablood $x = a$ might not satisfy the inequality.

Comment: If it doesn't then $p-.... $ oops.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1.

If $p = 2$, the result is incorrect, so assume $p > 2$. Let $N = [\sqrt{p}]$. Consider the $N + 1$ numbers $0, a, 2a, \dots Na \pmod{p}$. These numbers are all distinct because $a$ is invertible modulo $p$. There must be two of them, say $ka$ and $la$, that differ by less than $p/( N + 1) < \sqrt{p}$ (considered cyclically modulo $p$). Then letting $y = |k - l| \in [1,N]$, we must have $x = \pm ya \pmod{p} \in [1,N])$. Thus $x^2 + 2y^2 = y^2(a^2 + 2) = 0 \mod{p}$.

Part 2.

$n$ is divisible by $p$ but is less than $3p$.

Part 3.

If $n = p$, the result is clear. If $n = 2p$, then $x$ must be even, say, $x = 2x'$. Then $p = y^2 + 2(x')^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Oops.  Can't delete on the phone app.  Oh, well. It's late.

Ignore.

1) if $a < \sqrt {p} $ Let $x=a $ and $y=1$

The $x^2+2y^2\equiv -2+2\equiv 0\mod p $.

If $a >\sqrt {a}$ Let $x=p-a$, $y=1$.

2) $0 <n=x^2+2y^2<3p $.  And $n\equiv 0 \mod p $ so $n=p $ or $2p $.

3) if $p=n=x^2+2y^2$ We are done.

Otherwise $p=\frac n2=\frac {x^2}2+ y^2$.  That is an integer so $2|x^2$ so $2|x $.  Let $x=2z $ and $p =\frac {4z^2}{2}+y^2=y^2+2z^2$.